# Android: How can I start an activity from a regular java class? the java class is servlet

Tags: android

How can I start an activity from a servlet? I have an i-Jetty server installed and a servlet that responds to HTTP request.  I would like to start an activity from the servlet, does any body have any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do it the other way: have an Android `Service` that will periodically query that servlet and decide whether to launch an Activity (or rather show a notification). `AlarmManager` might also come handy for this.

Comment: I'm not following you on how to query the servlet.

Comment: @yanchenko - could you please elaborate. I also need the same thing and could use the help. Thanks.